# Functions called when showing and hiding uisearchcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

What functions are called that I can use/override when a UISearchController's search bar is tapped and when the Cancel is tapped?

I want to do things (like adjust table view offset) when the search bar and scope bar options are shown and then hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UISearchBarDelegate` functions. Set your view controller as a delegate of `searchController.searchBar` and implement needed functions. The docs is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html).